# Autolayout - UIView does not resize correctly to subview's size

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

I'm trying to programmatically create a `UIView` with a `UILabel` as a subview using autolayout.

**Constraints**

I used the following constraints on `view`:

- **CenterX** of `view` to `fastAttacksContainerView` *(superview)*.
- **Top** constraint of constant 8 to superview.
- Then created a `label` which is a subview of `view` and added constraints of constant 8 for **Top**, **Bottom**, **Left**, and **Right** to `view`.

**Problem**

The `view` only resizes to the **frame** of the label and does not account for the 4 constraints of constant 8 on all 4 sides. Which causes the `label` to be displayed partially outside the `view`.

```
let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = pokemon.secondaryColor

let label = UILabel()

fastAttacksContainerView.addSubview(view)
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(label)
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

label.text = fa

let gest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.selectFastAttack))
view.addGestureRecognizer(gest)

fastAttackButtons.append(view)
fastAttackLables.append(label)

let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: fastAttacksContainerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: fastAttacksContainerView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

let labLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
let labTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
let labRigth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
let labBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
view.addConstraints([labLeft, labTop, labRigth, labBottom])
fastAttacksContainerView.addConstraints([top, centerX])
```

**Output**

[image: Simulation]

Comment: why you don't use storyboard?

Comment: The above-mentioned code is to be iterated as the number of `view`s is fetched at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`view` has ambiguous height.

You should add constraint for height of `view` or distance from it to bottom of `fastAttacksContainerView`.

Comment: Doesn't `view` take the height of `label` + 8 on **Top** and + 8 on **Bottom**?

Comment: try replace `view.addConstraints([labLeft, labTop, labRigth, labBottom])` with `label.addConstraints([labLeft, labTop, labRigth, labBottom])`

Comment: The program crashed with `The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint` error.

Comment: put `fastAttacksContainerView.addConstraints...` before `view.addConstraints...`

Comment: I added an answer that worked for me. There seems to be a bug, I interchanged `item` and `toItem` for `Leading` and `Trailing` and I worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by making a similar setup on storyboard and copying the constraints in.

**Things that I changed:**

- Used `Leading` and `Trailing` instead of `Left` and `Right` layout attributes.
- For the `labLeft` and `labRight` constraints, I interchanged `item` and `toItem`. (This seems like a bug to me. Can anyone verify, please?)

**Code change:**

```
let labLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
let labTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
let labRigth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
let labBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
```